# pandas read_csv with index in every second column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv-file with severel values for several stocks that looks like this:

```
date                stock_A  date               stock_B  date      stock_C
30.10.2017 09:00    3223     30.10.2017 09:00   53234    ...       .....
30.10.2017 09:02    2544     30.10.2017 09:01   24337    ...       .....
30.10.2017 09:04    925      30.10.2017 09:02   4529     ...       .....    
30.10.2017 09:05    3210     30.10.2017 09:03   8534     ...       .....
```

As you can see, every second column is a datetime index. However, it is not in the same order/frequency. Is there a way to import this data with pandas such that I get only one index and the data is mapped accordingly?

I already tried this code:

```
pd.read_csv(file, sep=";", header=0, index_col=['date'], parse_dates=True, dtype=object)
```

But it only imports the first row as index and the other dates as columns with values. However, I would like to have my DataFrame as follows:

```
date                stock_A  stock_B  stock_C
30.10.2017 09:00    3223     53234    122
30.10.2017 09:01    0        24337    1215  
30.10.2017 09:02    2544     4529     0 
30.10.2017 09:03    0        8534     1354
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension with [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `DatetimeIndex` for each pair:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=";")

a = df.columns[::2]
b = df.columns[1::2]

df=pd.concat([df[[j]].set_index(pd.to_datetime(df[i])) for i, j in zip(a,b)],axis=1).fillna(0)
print (df)
                     stock_A  stock_B
2017-10-30 09:00:00   3223.0  53234.0
2017-10-30 09:01:00      0.0  24337.0
2017-10-30 09:02:00   2544.0   4529.0
2017-10-30 09:03:00      0.0   8534.0
2017-10-30 09:04:00    925.0      0.0
2017-10-30 09:05:00   3210.0      0.0
```

Last for column from index:

```
df = df.rename_axis('date').reset_index()
print (df)
                 date  stock_A  stock_B
0 2017-10-30 09:00:00   3223.0  53234.0
1 2017-10-30 09:01:00      0.0  24337.0
2 2017-10-30 09:02:00   2544.0   4529.0
3 2017-10-30 09:03:00      0.0   8534.0
4 2017-10-30 09:04:00    925.0      0.0
5 2017-10-30 09:05:00   3210.0      0.0
```